# Git / Perforce Exclusion Rules - to allow ignoring if a sibling file exists?

Tags: git, typescript, perforce

We are starting to look at TypeScript, and we don't want to check in the corresponding .js files when a .ts file is present, but to check them in when they don't have a corresponding .ts file.

file.ts
file.js (don't check me in! I have a sibling file.ts! )

foo.js (check me in fine, I am not transpiled from ts!)

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to go about this is to organize all your `.ts` and their corresponding `.js` files into a subfolder, and use [`.gitignore`](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) to ignore `.js` files in that subfolder.

For example, if we have a project layout that looks like:

```
apps
 |-- *.js  # many JS files
 |-- ts    # subfolder containing all .ts files and their siblings .js files
     |-- *.ts
     |-- *.js
```

Then you can add a `.gitignore` to the project root level with the pattern:

```
ts/*.js
```

Alternately, you can also put all the sibling `*.js` files into another completely separate subfolder, and ignore that subfolder altogether.

Comment: Note that in Perforce you seem to have to use a backslash instead of a slash (at least at Windows), so: `ts\*.js`

Comment: While I think this is a solution it doesn't answer the question. Is it possible to craft a rule that allows for files to be ignored if they have a sibling.

Answer (score 1):

I wound up doing a blanket *.js.* ignore, and then excluding each folder by hand that I wanted to allow js's in.

```
*.js.*
!spg/bower_components/*
!spg/Gruntfile.js
!spg/na_components/*
```